# Magento 2 : pass custom value in js from ui form

Tags: magento2, admin, ui-form

I want to pass some custom value from ui form field. How to pass it and get in js?

**code :**

```
<field name="template_text_4">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source\GetTemplate</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Select Template Text 4</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">template_text_4</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">template_text_4</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/js/getTemplateText</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
```

I call `Vendor_Module/js/getTemplateText` this js file. How to pass some custom value from this field ?

Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: Based on that custom value what you want to do?

Comment: I just want to pass single custom text

Answer (score 1):

In your component JS file :

> Vendor_Module/js/getTemplateText

```
define([
'underscore',
'Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select'
], function (_, Column) {
'use strict';

return Column.extend({
    defaults: {
        bodyTmpl: 'Vendor_Module/ui/grid/cells/text'
    },
    getCustomFunction: function (row) {            
        console.log(row.template_text_4);
    }
});
});
```

Create a html file :

> Vendor_Module/ui/grid/cells/text

```
<div class="data-grid-cell-content" data-bind="attr: { class: $col.getCustomFunction($row())}" text="$col.getLabel($row())"/>
```

Using `data-bind="attr: { class: $col.getCustomFunction($row())}"` i am append custom class to specific column.

I hope it helps!

Comment: You are welcome :) +1 for a nice question.

Comment: If my answer is useful to you then accept an answer so it will be useful to another user.